# Active then deactivate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" inside my team site

Tags: 2013, development, feature, publishing-site

i have a team site inside my SharePoint 2013. now i have enable the  "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" from site Setting-->site collection features. which added the following libraries automatically (mark with NEW) :-

[image]

now i have deactivate the  "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" again, but the above libraries still exists , so can anyone advice why deactivating the  "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" features did not delete the libraries which were automatically created when activating it ?

**second question**, These libraries do not contain any data , so can i remove them manually ?

**third question** , if i remove the libraries manually , and in the future i chose to activate the " SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure " again, will this cause any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. SharePoint will not remove those libraries.

You can manually remove those and it will not cause any problems.

Later if you activate the Publishing feature will create those if it doesn't exists.